# Why is my json data not being fetched from an each loop with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a set of data that is created/pulled from a url that has already got parsed json data like so:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"school_name": "another school in essex",
"website": null,
"book_id": 27,
"url": "http://localhost:3000/schools/1.json"
},
{
"id": 2,
"school_name": "ddffdfd",
"website": null,
"book_id": 31,
"url": "http://localhost:3000/schools/2.json"
},
{
"id": 3,
"school_name": "ddfdfdffd",
"website": null,
"book_id": 31,
"url": "http://localhost:3000/schools/3.json"
},
{
"id": 4,
"school_name": "4545455454",
"website": null,
"book_id": 31,
"url": "http://localhost:3000/schools/4.json"
}
]
```

I have got a .each loop that grabs the data and assigns it to (city) parameter so I can grab that city parameter and loop through and just grab what I want from that json out put and use.

```
var info = '/schools.json';

$.get(info, function(response) {
  var jsonData = response
  var mapContent = $('').html();
  var json = jsonData;
}

function setMarkers(map, json) {
  jQuery.each(json, function (index, city) {
     console.log(city[id]);
   }
}
```

When I try and access the json object in the .each loop above it gives nothing. How can I access the id from each of the json outputs?

Cheers

Comment: You don't call setMarkers, so your each loop isn't going to do anything... Aside from that, you have some other weird things in your code. I'd suggest to clean it up first, to answer this would be to rewrite just about every line.

Comment: How do you call setMarkers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you didn't called the setMarkers function, also, you didn't close the $.get function. Also when you get values from an object you should use obj['value'] or obj.value

```
var info = '/schools.json';

$.get(info, {}, function(response) {
  var mapContent = $('').html();
  setMarkers(mapContent, response);
}, 'json');

function setMarkers(map, json) {
  jQuery.each(json, function (index, city) {
     console.log(city['id']);
   }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick, I think my function was wrong but not completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get(info,PARAMS, function(response) {
    var jsonData = response
    var mapContent = $('').html();
    var json = jsonData;
},"json");
```

I think you forgot the closing ');' and a function parameter: 'PARAMS' that can be null
Just try adding "json" as final argument.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

your code should return `ReferenceEerror: id is not defined`. use `city["id"]` or `city.id` instead.

And check that json is valid json object, not string